# Azure B2C modify SAML AccessTokenLifetime

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0

I have some problem with my SAML custom policy in Azure B2C.
One of my connected apps did not want me to login with my SAML response. I asked the support of that app and they told me the error message is something like "The request exceeds the allowable time to live".

So I had a look for my SAMLResponse and the conditions are:

```
<saml:Conditions NotBefore="2020-03-20T21:59:43.5226812Z"
                     NotOnOrAfter="2020-03-20T22:04:43.5226812Z">
```

I requested the resource 22:59 but the response is responding with NotOnOrAfter="2020-03-20T22:04:43 which is in the past.
So. My app is running in my timezone and maybe it is refusing it because of this.

I tried to change the value for "NotOnOrAfter" to +1 hour, but that's not as easy as I hoped.
In [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#saml-tokens) for the normal Azure AD it's documented to change the AccessTokenLifetime. So I followed [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-manage-sso-and-token-config#token-lifetimes-and-claims-configuration) to change it to one hour in my TrustFrameworkBase.xml. That is working great for my JWT testapp with the custom B2C_1A_signup_signin policy, but it has no effect to my NotOnOrAfter of my SAML policy although when I add the documented lines to my SAML RP Technical Profile.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also tried to add Policcies with Powershell for that app, but no effect too. Token is just 5min valid. I found some setting inside SP to disable date condition check for SAML. So it's okay for me.